# Installing pip-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, azure, pip

I have a ubuntu machine , where I have to install Azure Python SDK:

**1**. When I execute this command:

**curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | sudo python**

I get a message as :

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

**2.** Next when I issue this command

**sudo /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 install azure**

sudo: /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7: command not found

I am not sure why is this happening ...Any solution for this?

Comment: Just do `sudo pip install azure`.

Comment: I get a response as follows  :                               Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): azure in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.                                             So, is the installation successful ? If so whats the difference between pip2.7 and pip-2.7

Comment: pip-2.7 is the name of the package, but the binary would simply be called pip. And it does seem like you already have azure. You can upgrade using the --upgrade option.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik, `pip-2.7` is also the name of the executable. Also I see both `pip2.7` and `pip-2.7` installed in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo pip install azure
```

If you have both python2 and python3, try:

```
sudo pip2 install azure
```