# pip2.7 error while installing mayavi

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am using pip2.7 and trying to install mayavi. I run
    sudo pip2.7 install mayavi and get this error

```
from .dist import _get_unpatched
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in    <module>
packaging = pkg_resources.packaging
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'
```

actually error log is longer but I think this part is critical.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320481/installing-pip-2-7) could help.

It seems that pip2.7 and pip-2.7 aren't at the same location.

Comment: thank you for your reply MaxD but when I type pip and tab for auto complete it does not show pip-2.7 so what should I do any idea

Comment: I just tried it on a VM Linux Mint (17.1 32b) and I had the choice between `pip` and `pip2`. It nearly worked with `pip` and `pip2` (just an ImportError on vtk module). Do you tried [easy_install](http://www.hacksparrow.com/ubuntu-how-to-install-easy_install.html)?

Comment: easy_install log is like that                                                                     Searching for mayavi
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mayavi/
Best match: mayavi 4.4.3
Downloading http://www.enthought.com/repo/ets/mayavi-4.4.3.tar.gz
error: Can't download http://www.enthought.com/repo/ets/mayavi-4.4.3.tar.gz: 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Hum, did you install the [requirement packages](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html#installing-ready-made-distributions) before?

Comment: actually I saw that other people had this error and reported it on github page. They say there is a pull and after that it should be fixed. I downloaded branch:feature/python3 and it seems that it passed that part without error. It uses setuptools and it tries to download traitsui and its dependincies and I get  Downloading http://www.enthought.com/repo/ets/traits-4.5.0.tar.gz
error: Can't download http://www.enthought.com/repo/ets/traits-4.5.0.tar.gz: 404 NOT FOUND   error. I installed those with pip succesfully but it tries to install by setuptools and fails :(